# How to generate the Encrypted_Value for CEK in SQL Server (Always Encrypted) using Python

Tags: python, sql-server, jks, always-encrypted

I'm trying to know if there's a way in Python for generating the Encrypted_Value for CEK in SQL Server (Always Encrypted). The driver used was 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'. By the way, I'm using Java KeyStore for the repository of cryptographic keys and certificates.

Thank you so much.

```sql
CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY MyCEK   
WITH VALUES  
(  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = MyCMK,   
    ALGORITHM = 'RSA_OAEP',   
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE = (????)
);
```